# Find row with time difference>10 years

Tags: r

```
individual_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
year <- c(2000, 2010, 2011, 2014, 2024, 2005, 2012, 2026, 2027, 2039)
df <- data.frame(individual_id, year)
```

I have a df with individual_id and year. For each individual, I want to find the first year (the first row of each individual), and the "second year" which is 10 years larger than the first year, and the "third year" which is 10 years larger than the second year, and so on.

Here is the output data that I want

```
individual_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
year <- c(2000, 2011, 2024, 2005,  2026, 2039)
out.df <- data.frame(individual_id, year)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `accumulate()` to return values when the difference is more than ten else retain the previous value then `filter()` by matching years.  To avoid duplicated years, you can make the data `distinct()` first:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  # arrange(year) %>%              # If data needs to be sorted
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(individual_id) %>%
  filter(accumulate(year, ~ if (.y - .x > 10) .y else .x) == year)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   individual_id [2]
  individual_id  year
          <dbl> <dbl>
1             1  2000
2             1  2011
3             1  2024
4             2  2005
5             2  2026
6             2  2039
```

Comment: I like the use of `accumulate`, but you likely want to `arrange(year)` in case the data is out of order to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`. First, group by individual and arrange by year. Then calculate an index that is the floor of the difference between the year and the minimum year for that individual divided by 10. Then regroup by individual and index and filter for those rows where the year is the minimum for that index.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(individual_id) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(index = floor(((year - min(year))/10))) %>%
  group_by(individual_id,index) %>%
  dplyr::filter(year == min(year))
## A tibble: 6 x 3
## Groups:   individual_id, index [6]
#  individual_id  year index
#          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1             1  2000     0
#2             2  2005     0
#3             1  2010     1
#4             1  2024     2
#5             2  2026     2
#6             2  2039     3
```

You could get rid of the index by using `dplyr::select(-index)`.